# Calling Python functions passed by weakref

Tags: c++, python, boost

Using Boost.Python, is there a way to call a Python function that's been passed through a `weakref`? The following code doesn't work:

```
import weakref

def foo():
    print 'it works'

def func():
    return weakref.ref(foo)
```

The following is the C++:

```
object module = import("test");
object func(module.attr("func"));
object foo = func();
foo(); // Should print 'it works', but it prints nothing
```

However, if I pass the function object without weakref, it all works fine. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: I don't know if this carries over into C++ land, but calling a `weakref.ref` just returns a strong reference to the object (or `None`) in Python...

Comment: @delnan According to the documentation, it returns a weak reference. But I don't really understand the difference between ref() and proxy().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [weakref documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref):

> Return a weak reference to object. **The original object can be retrieved by calling the reference object** if the referent is still alive...

So, given your snippet:

```
import weakref

def foo():
    print "It Works!"

def func():
    return weakref.ref(foo)

ref = func() # func returns the reference to the foo() function
original_func = ref() # calling the reference returns the referenced object
original_func() # prints "It Works!"
```

Answer (score 4):

This may solve it for you.

```
>>> import weakref
>>> def foo(): print 'it works'
...
>>> x = weakref.ref(foo)
>>> x()()
it works
>>> x()
<function foo at 0x7f56c10acc80>
```